# Hartl tutorial chapter 9.3.3 pagination (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pagination, railstutorial.org

I was working on the part 9.3.3 about pagination from the ruby on rails tutorial of Michael Hartl, an Im stuck: running the rspec tests i got an error message that there is something wrong with the gem FactoryGirl. Do you suppose what could be a problem?

```
/Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/definition_proxy.rb:43:in `add_attribute': Both value and block given (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/definition_proxy.rb:102:in `method_missing'
from /Users/smi/projects/sample_app/spec/factories.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
from /Users/smi/projects/sample_app/spec/factories.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
from /Users/smi/projects/sample_app/spec/factories.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/ge......................
```

users_pages_spec.rb:

```
 describe "pagination" do

  before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
  after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

  it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

  it "should list each user" do
    User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
      expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
    end
  end
end
```

factories.rb:

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequense(:name)   { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequense(:email)  { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer! the method "sequence" in factories.rb was written with a mistake. Now all tests are green.

Comment: Made same mistake, mistyped word `trait`. Error message is very unhelpful.